# указать тип переменной из другой переменной

Tags: c#

Есть две совершенно одинаковые функции, которые ищут среди множества входящих объектов, первый объект с интерфейсом назовем его Х и вся разница заключается в том что отдают они  объекты с разными интерфейсами, подскажите мне как в C# в функции указать тип возвращаемого элемента не кодом а через переменную

**Пример:**

```
IMyTextPanel getTextPanel()
{
    List<IMyTextPanel> TextPanels = new List<IMyTextPanel>();
    GridTerminalSystem.GetBlocksOfType<IMyTextPanel>(TextPanels);
    IMyTextPanel TextPanel;
    if (TextPanels.Count > 0) return TextPanels[0];
    return null;
}
IMyGyro getGyro()
{
    List<IMyGyro> Gyros = new List<IMyGyro>();
    GridTerminalSystem.GetBlocksOfType<IMyGyro>(Gyros);
    IMyGyro Gyro;
    if (Gyros.Count > 0) return Gyro = Gyros[0];
    return null;
}
```

Хотелось бы что то на подобии:

```
getCube(string interface)
{
    List<interface> Cubes= new List<interface>();
    GridTerminalSystem.GetBlocksOfType<interface>(Cubes);
    if (Cubes.Count > 0) return Cubes[0];
    return null;
}
```

но программа ругается на это

я так понимаю у функции должен быть некий формат возвращаемого, что то вроде obj, а вот внутри не знаю что должно быть

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне кажется, это подходящий юзкейс для генериков.

```
T GetWhatever<T>() where T: class
{
    var items = new List<T>();
    GridTerminalSystem.GetBlocksOfType<T>(items);
    return Items.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

и вызывать соответственно как `TextPanel tp = GetWhatever<IMyTextPanel>();` или `IMyGyro gyro = GetWhatever<IMyGyro>();`.

Возможно, вам понадобятся и другие ограничения на `T`, если их налагает `GetBlocksOfType`.

Comment: И да, а почему `GetBlocksOfType` не возвращает результат через возвращаемое значение?

Comment: Дело в том что он ничего не возвращает void, а лишь формирует  список http://spaceengineerswiki.com/IMyGridTerminalSystem/ru

Comment: @Mcile: А, это не ваш интерфейс, а сторонний. Тогда это вопрос к ним, а не к вам, конечно.